# Big crash out of nowhere?

Tags: debian, crash

So I was using my laptop (drawing in Krita with a Wacom tablet on Debian Wheezy) and the screen suddenly turned blue (like a Windows crash dump) and now looks like the attached image:

[image]

Does anyone understand what is going on?
The screen is now frozen like this. What's worse, the power button isn't working now, so I can't restart. What can I do now, besides wait for the battery to die?

Comment: you might remove your battery to reboot the machine. Also, almost every laptop would physically turn itself off if you'll hold your powerbutton for ~5 secs. After that, you want to get logs from /var/log (I'm not exactly sure what do you want to get from there on wheezy) and post them, since this image is inconclusive.

Comment: Alright, I don't have screwdrivers at the moment so I guess if the battery doesn't run out by morning I will take it out. And yes, I've been holding the power button down for a long time, nothing happens. Can any hints at all be gleaned from the image? I'm afraid I don't understand what's going on there. Also will check logs if booting up again works. That's what I'm worried about...

Comment: Update: Power ran out in the morning, so I plugged the charger in. After a few seconds, I turned the power on and the usual lights displaying that the computer is on and charging lit up, but the screen was completely dark, which worried me quite a bit.
Later in the day I retried that and the computer booted up (good thing, I thought my CPU fried or something). I'm looking through /var/log/, but there is a lot in there...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38608/how-to-determine-why-my-computer-crashed <- this link might help. However, this might be outdated since Debian got `upgraded` to systemd.

Comment: one more thought - what I'd do was to `grep -R ` 110381 timestamp through /var/logs. It would yield the file you need (chances are that it would be not only that file, but you'll be able to deduct what exact log file do you need).